# MvvmCross as "Native" Libraries

Tags: xamarin, servicestack, mvvmcross

I have a project which greatly depends on ServiceStack, unfortunately the V4 releases, which includes PCL release for most platforms(especially after forking out for a Xamarin Licence), is just way out of my price range as an ISV. I have cloned the MvvmCross code but before I start messing around I would like to know what pitfalls I could run into when attempting to create a Non PCL based version compatible with the platforms I target (Currently Xamarin.Android, WPF and WinRT). The idea would be to able to reuse the code for the WPF project to build Android and WinRT clients.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What portions of ServiceStack you need? I have majority of the v3 abstracted into PCL compatible code. All of Text, majority of OrmLite, Redis could also be abstracted but I don't see that many use cases for it.

Comment: @SKall basically just the client libraries, ServiceStack.Text, ServiceStack.Common and ServiceStack.Interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem or pitfall with what you are describing - and I don't think you'll need to fork the MvvmCross source.

You should be able to build your apps as native code, and should then be able to reference the MvvmCross PCL libraries directly from the native libraries you are building - you don't need to rebuild MvvmCross to do this. Plenty of people already use MvvmCross using "file linking" rather than PCLs - it's not the default setup encouraged by the Nuget packages, but it still works fine.

Comment: Thank you Stuart. I will have a go at this. Really don't want to rebuild my whole solution from scratch.

Comment: I get the following build error: `
Error 36  cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Spinner(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int,int)
location: class android.widget.Spinner
  super (p0, p1, p2, p3);
Debug\android\src\cirrious\mvvmcross\binding\droid\views\MvxSpinner.java 43 3`
 Any ideas?

Comment: Try http://redth.codes/such-android-api-levels-much-confuse-wow/ - and if that fails try a new question with lots of info

Comment: thanks, I played around with the target settings and got it to work flawlessly